# Посчитать количество вхождений слов в предложение и вывести матрицу результата

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Всем доброго времени суток! У меня есть два списка: в первом предложения (их 22), во втором слова (их 254, все уникальные). Нужно получить результирующую матрицу, в которой элемент `[i][j]` представляет собой количество вхождений j-ого слова в i-ое предложение. Я пробовал сделать через .count(), но получается что-то неадекватное (например, 7 вхождений одного слова в одно предложение)

делал так:

```
for i in range(22):
    for j in range(254):
        word_matrix[i][j] = sentences[i].count(listofwords[j])
```

(и получал  7 и 13 вхождений уникального слова в предложение)
Как сделать по-человечески?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему вам нужен [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

text = """Всем доброго времени суток! У меня есть два списка: в первом предложения(их 22), во втором слова(их 254,все уникальные). Нужно получить результирующую матрицу, в которой элемент [i][j] представляет собой количество вхождений j-ого слова в i-ое предложение. Я пробовал сделать через .count(), но получается что-то неадекватное(например, 7 вхождений одного слова в одно предложение)"""

vocabulary = ['слова', 'списка', 'предложения', 'вхождений']

cv = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)

r = pd.SparseDataFrame(cv.fit_transform(sent_tokenize(text)),
                       columns=cv.get_feature_names(),
                       default_fill_value=0)
```

результат:

```
In [75]: r
Out[75]:
   слова  списка  предложения  вхождений
0      0       0            0          0
1      1       1            1          0
2      1       0            0          1
3      1       0            0          1
```